# Google Chrome Extension Alert on Click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do i display an Alert message instead of the pop up.

My goal is to launch a script when the user clicks the extensions icon. The pop up is unnecessary, in fact i would like to avoid letting the pop up to initiate all together. I want my extension to behave like the Gmail hyper link, but instead of opening a link, I want it to execute my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [the api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked).

You will want to remove the popup in your manifest and have a `onClicked` handler instead. It will look like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
  alert("stuff");
});
```

The important part is that you don't define a `popup` in your manifest as it prevents the event from firing.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than a popup, I'm assuming you want to run a background script to listen for a browserAction event.

First, make sure you remove "default_popup": "popup.html" from your manifest.json. Then include the background script in "background".

Your manifest json should be something like this:

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "image.png",
  "default_title": "My Extension"
},

"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
```